# Flutter app build failed License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, licensing

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /home/maruf/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: /home/maruf/Android/Sdk

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to accept licenses with flutter doctor?

1. Open your terminal
2. Type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. Accept licenses by typing `y` and `ENTER`

Comment: Yeah my terminal also suggest the following command but the command isn't working :(

Comment: Do you have Android Studio? If you have you can check SDK manager to accept licenses.